# Updating an expiring certificate on VSTO outlook plugin causes end users to fail

Tags: c#, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

Visual Studio 2012
.Net 4.5 Framework
ClickOnce Deployment c# VSTO Outlook addin
Addin is set to check for updates every time it starts (each time outlook is opened)

Addin is signed with digital certificate from GoDaddy with Sha1 encryption and is expiring in two weeks.  So we got a new certificate with Sha2 encryption.

I added the cert to the store as per all the instructions and I can select it from the store in the publish settings designer in Visual Studio.

Here is my problem:

After I add the new cert and publish the new version the next time the addin updates. The addin gets an error saying it's untrusted and thus outlook disables the addin altogether.

The exception the end user gets when it tries to update is:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work             because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for 
The Addin or its location is not      trusted.   Contact your administrator for further assistance.
 at 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal(ClickOnceTrustPromptKeyValue promptKeyValue, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustUsingPromptKey(Uri manifest, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

The only way I can fix it, is if I put the old cert back in and republish.  But the user has to go enable the addin manually.  Once they do, it runs just fine. This will work for a couple of weeks, as that's when the old cert is set to expire, but I need to find out why the new cert is breaking.

I have googled and found that this problem existed prior .Net 3.5, but everything I've seen (so far) says that using the higher framework versions this problem shouldn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue I found is that the SHA-2 encryption from GoDaddy isn't yet fully trusted.  So we just re-keyed our cert back to SHA-1 for now and everything works as expected.  Maybe next year (when we have to do this again) we will try SHA-2.